# How to add CORS support to Wordpress RSS2 feed?

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers, cors, rss2

I am trying to add CORS (http://enable-cors.org/) support to an RSS2 feed within a custom Wordpress theme. I have tried the following, all to no avail:

1. Following the instructions on https://web.archive.org/web/20140314152828/http://bowdenweb.com:80/wp/2011/05/how-to-enable-cors-in-wordpress.html, I attempted to modify the theme's header.php file and add the following code to it:

   `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

   This was successful in adding the CORS header to the Wordpress posts, but *not* to the RSS2 feed.
2. Then, I attempted to use the "Plugin API / Action Reference", i.e. the `add_action` function (http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

   I added the following code to header.php:

   ```
   function add_cors_headers()
   {
       header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
   }

   add_action('rss2_head','add_cors_headers');
   ```

Again, no success. Now I am at a dead end. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding your code you mentioned in 2. to your `functions.php` file?  You mentioned you added it to the `header.php` file when the Wordpress documentation states it should be included in `functions.php`.

Comment: I created a ticket in WP where asked to add this functionality https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50441#ticket
Also in details of the ticket you may find a security concern.

Answer (score 11):

You could do it like this with a plugin or by adding to functions. I think that ends up being cleaner.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_header_origin', 9 );

function add_header_origin() {
    if (is_feed()){
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    }
}
```

Comment: Tiny improvement, using the dedicated action `do_feed_rss2` and setting priority to less than 10 (ref: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Feed_Actions ) : `add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'add_header_origin', 9 );`

Answer (score 2):

Copy the original rss-template "wp-includes/feed-rss2.php" to your theme directory and activate it by adding this code to your functions.php:

```
remove_all_actions( 'do_feed_rss2' );
add_action( 'do_feed_rss2', 'my_feed_rss2', 10, 1 );

function my_feed_rss2( $for_comments ) {
    $rss_template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/feed-rss2.php';

    if( file_exists( $rss_template ) )
        load_template( $rss_template );
    else
        do_feed_rss2( $for_comments ); // Call default function
}
```

Then you can modify your rss-template and add the header like mentioned by jefffederman.

Answer (score -1):

Go to wp-includes/feed-rss2.php and below

```
header('Content-Type: ' . feed_content_type('rss-http') . '; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'), true);
```

add

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Comment: This solution requires the modification of core Wordpress files, which would be overwritten when Wordpress is upgraded (which happens frequently).  I would suggest a solution that uses an action hook within the theme's function.php file to include the additional header.

Comment: Also add ob_start(); at the top of the page. There is chance that server might have already start sending data to client, after that headers cannot be set.

Comment: Never ever modify core WordPress files. @Axel explains it very well why and what to to to avoid the editing.